# lambda expression get item from list

Tags: c#

I have made a small application to practice lambda expressions. I am new to using this technique and I want to become familiar with using them in my day to day coding as I realise how powerful they can be.

I have made a Class named `Pet` each pet has a `Name` and an `Age` I have added 4 pets to my `Pet` class.

I want to get the pets name who has an age of 1 using a `Where` and `Select` clause. However when I run my code instead of returning the pets name I get `System.Collections.Generic.List 1 [System.String]`

My code is as follows

Pet class

```
   class Pet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Program Class

```
        var pets = new Pet[]
        {
            new Pet {Name="Sharo", Age=8 },
            new Pet {Name="Rex", Age=4 },
            new Pet {Name="Strela", Age=1 },
            new Pet {Name="Bora",Age=1 }
        };

p = pets.Where(pet => pet.Age == 1).Select(pet => pet.Name).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Comment: What output you expect? The linq query is returning you the collection of result. In your code this will be collection of names. You need to loop thru it to get the actual value. If you are sure that the linq query will return only one result then you should use FirstOrDefault instead of ToList. This will give you the first item of the result collection

Comment: Maybe you expect only one, then use `First` or `Single`(throws exception if more than one). `string petname = pets.First(p => p.Age == 1).Name;`. Note that this throws a `NullRefernceException` if there are none, you can use `Console.WriteLine(pets.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Age == 1)?.Name);`

Comment: If you want to practice Lambda expressions(delegate type or expression type). What I would suggest is implementing you own Where, Select, GroupBy... method extensions. Lambdas are much more useful then LINQ. And basic implementation is the linq methods is not all that difficult to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(p)
```

implicitely calls the `ToString()` method of object `p`, which by default returns the typename.

Use instead

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", p));
```

The rest of your code looks perfectly correct.

note : if you want to practice lambdas a bit more, you can get the string concat with linq's aggregate :

```
Console.WriteLine(p.Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `ToList` you have `List<String>`

Instead you can do

```
foreach(var pet in p)
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name)
```